# Is an SKAction automatically removed after it completed?

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

This is regarding Actions in SpriteKit.
Is an SKAction automatically removed after it completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If theres no references left for it, then yes. If you're doing one time actions they will get removed automatically.